# Char Array vs String: which is better for storing a set of letters

Tags: java, performance, coding-style, constants

I need to store in a constant class 4 letter of a code. I can do:

```
static final String CODE_LETTERS = "TRWAG";
```

or

```
static final char[] CODE_LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G'};
```

After, I can obtain one of that characters in two ways:

```
final char codeLetter = CODE_LETTERS.charAt(index);
```

or

```
final char codeLetter = CODE_LETTERS[index];
```

what is the best way?. Please take in mind correction, performance, etc.

Comment: Looks like 5 letters :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance is irrelevant in this case.  If it's really supposed to be constant, you can't use the `char[]` approach.  Consider:

```
public class Test
{
  static final char[] CODE_LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G'};

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println(CODE_LETTERS[0]); // T
    CODE_LETTERS[0] = 'x';
    System.out.println(CODE_LETTERS[0]); // x
  }
}
```

Comment: Who says performance is irrelevant? Lots of people spend a lot of effort on performance. Of course the implementation can do naughty things, but if the representation is localised we can just say "don't do that then".

Comment: I meant it's not a question of performance, because the char[] version doesn't even work as intended. Let's concentrate on correcting the obvious errors IN THIS CASE: premature optimization, and using an array as a constant.

Comment: I edited my answer after the exchange above and added the "in this case" qualifier. I'm mentioning it here to avoid confusing readers too badly.

Answer (score 9):

Neither is incorrect, but since you're going to be dealing with the `char`s individually I'd personally use the `char []`. That said, the impact this will have on performance is going to be negligible if even measurable.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are going to fetch the character several million times in a row, you don't need to bother about the performance.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Seriously: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*

Comment: But equally one should not pessimize prematurely. For a fixed length immutable string a char array will always be quicker and have less memory overhead than the equiavlent std::string object.

Comment: It may well be the sort of thing that gets done lots of times. What if this was a new method in the implementation of `java.lang.String`?

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable, char[] is not. If you are defining this as a public "constant" in a class then String is the real constant.

For example if you have this:

```
public class MyClass { 
    public static final char[] CODE_LETTERS = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    ....
}
```

I can be all sneaky and do this:

```
MyClass.CODE_LETTERS[0] = 'Q';
```

Bam, I've changed the value of your "constant".

The `final` keyword only affects the reference to the array, it does not apply to the array elements. I see a similar mistake all the time with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`, people think its protecting their list but client code can still access and modify the list elements.

So to answer your question, use the String.

Answer (score 5):

This is almost certainly a premature optimization. Whatever you save in performance by using a character array may be lost in readability if you need to give it to other methods, since it's more canonical to accept a `String` rather than a `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `String` does really match a set of `char`. So `char[]` as an implementation, although not meaning set, would not add the extra meaning of `String`. OTOH, you might find useful method in `String`. On the third hand, [java.util.Arrays](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) also has useful methods such as [binarySearch][2].

Perhaps what you want to do is introduce an abstraction for a set of `char` which might vary implementation between using `String` as the simplest that could possibly work, linear scanning of a `char[]` (fast if you don't scan very far), binary search, bit set. sparse bit set, hashed, flood filtered, etc.

[2]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(char[], int, int, char)

Answer (score 1):

Since a String uses a char[] to hold your letters the true answer is the char[] is faster. When in doubt look at the source, theres no magic in String, it just uses primitives like int and char[] just like any other class.

You really shouldnt care about something as trivial as this. A hell of a lot more happens within a program, that worrying about whether a single String is faster than using a char array.

Comment: Yes, but when a string is semantically meant to be used as a string instead of an array of characters then String should be used. Using char[] in Java only makes sense if you want to work with individual character items or need to frequently replace array positions.

Answer (score 1):

The only time that you will see a performance difference between the String and the character array is going to be under a profiler, and then only because the profiler will do the wrong thing. Modern JVMS (JDk 6+) will generate the same code for the two accesses once the JVM decides that this is hot enough to optimise.

To answer your question though; If you are using Java 5, use enumerations, if you are using something prior to Java5, use the [Java enumeration Pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html).

It will make your code more readable, as you won't need to keep track of the offsets somewhere, you can just use the enumeration. Additionally, it *will* be faster, since you will be able to do something like:

```
  final char codeLetter = enum.getCodeLetter();
```

Comment: There's no indication that enum is what he wants. If he is going to be using the characters as characters somewhere then it doesn't make sense to store them as enums.

Comment: If the enum values are T, R, W, A, G then toString() could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your should consider using an **enum**.
See [Enum Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Without knowing what the use is that's not a good suggestion. If he is going to compare the character against other characters then an enum doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I just wrote a [blog entry](http://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2011/04/24/java-characters-class.xhtml) about this yesterday. You need a specialized class wrapped around the char[]. My [Characters](https://svn.globalmentor.com/java/trunk/globalmentor-core/src/main/java/com/globalmentor/java/Characters.java) class is a lightweight way to keep an immutable set of characters, and provides highly efficient methods for things like searching. It's open source.

Comment: Your class would have sorted his characters on construction so it doesn't really answer his question, but I like the Idea behind the class. If I could +1 your blog post in its own right I would.

Comment: @ahcox, thanks for the nice words. I've added Facebook "like" capability to my blog site, so feel free to try that out! ;)